# Adobe Air communication with cmd

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, ping

Is there a way to communicate with cmd (using native process) in adobe air.
As an example;
How to send "ping www.google.com" to cmd and capture the return values in Air.

Edit

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5>ping www.google.com

Pinging www.l.google.com [209.85.175.103] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 209.85.175.103: bytes=32 time=1733ms TTL=50
Reply from 209.85.175.103: bytes=32 time=189ms TTL=50
Reply from 209.85.175.103: bytes=32 time=188ms TTL=50
Reply from 209.85.175.103: bytes=32 time=186ms TTL=50

Ping statistics for 209.85.175.103:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 186ms, Maximum = 1733ms, Average = 574ms

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5>
```

I can print above from Air application. I need to know is there a specific way to grab the values of Minimum = ?, Maximum = ? and Average = ?
Planning to explode the string. Is there another way. Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you can check that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on [Interacting with Native Processes in AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html). What you write in the command prompt (`ping` in your case) is another exe file located in a folder specified in the Windows Path. So you'll actually have to invoke the `ping.exe` with the `NativeProcess` class in AIR. OR, you could study how the exe works and then implement that logic in your AIR application.

**EDIT**

After you have edited your question, here are more details:

You use [Regular Expressions](http://regexlib.com/) (follow that link and learn about regular expressions)

Since you want to match this pattern

> Minimum = (number)ms, Maximum = (number)ms, Average = (number)ms

your  regular expression will look something like

```
var r:RegExp=/Minimum = ([\d\.]+)ms\, Maximum = ([\d\.]+)ms\, Average = ([\d\.]+)ms/i;

//Then, you execute this on your result string
var arr:Array=r.exec(result);

//Then check if the result matched your regex
if(arr != null) {
    var min:int=arr[1];
    var max:int=arr[2];
    var avg:int=arr[3];
} else {
    trace("invalid result from ping");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute shell command (e.g. ping,) you either need to run cmd.exe from it's location or run ping.exe. I found no direct way to execute shell commands in AIR, and execution of bat files is prohibited too. So, to call cmd.exe you need to know where it is. It's location given by environment variable `%ComSpec%` (I'm assuming we're talking about Windows,) but you can't get this value from AIR application too.
So, when I solved such a problem, I just bundled cmd.exe with my native AIR app. Not the best solution, because cmd.exe is taken on another OS. You can solve your problem this way:

- create native helper exe which executes 'echo %ComSpec%' and exits. You can use `system()` command to do that, see WinApi docs.
- in AIR app, run this helper and read console output.
- invoke cmd.exe using this path (you can specify /C argument for single commands.)

Or, if you prefer, create native exe which gets arguments from AIR app and executes them on the shell with `system()`. AIR app can then read console output from this exe. Less job for ActionScript, more for C++ (or whatever you use for native helper.)
**Update:**
If you already got ping output, just parse it with RegExp's, like
`"Reply from \d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}: bytes=32 time=(\d{1,})ms TTL=\d{1,}"`. Convert captured time string to int, then calculate min/max/averages.